# Continuous Surjective Map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R} ^ \infty$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve an exercise from Munkres:

Is there a continuous surjective map $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  ^\infty$ in the product topology? What about uniform and box topologies?

The answers I have found so far all use the idea of "gluing" some functions together. Specifically, notice that $\mathbb{R}^\infty = \cup_{n = 1} ^ \infty [-n, n] ^ n$ and we may define a continuous surjective map $f_n$ from $[n, n + 1]$ to $[-n, n] ^ n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Using some tricks I may choose the functions $f_n$ so that they agree on end points. However, what I do not understand is why the function $f$ obtained by gluing all these functions together is continuous. The pasting lemma should only work when the topological space is a finite union of closed subspaces right? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** It turns out that I can use local finiteness to finish the proof for product topology. However, I am stuck on proving or disproving the claim for uniform and box topogies on $\mathbb{R} ^ \infty$.

**Clarification** $\mathbb{R} ^ \infty$ is used to denote the space of all real sequences that are eventually $0$.

Comment: I don't know if all you said will work, but your very question has a positive answer : you just need the collection of closed subsets to be locally finite, i.e. each point must have a neighborhood which intersects a finite number of closed sets in your collection.

Comment: I see! I have used local finiteness to prove that my method works! Thank you!

Comment: The thing is : $[-n,n]^n$ is composed of real sequences which vanish at infinity, whatever big $n$ is. So, any sequence in the infinite union will also be a sequence vanishing at infinity, so that $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ is not the union you wrote.

Comment: Oh sorry I think it is a notation thing. In Munkres he used $\mathbb{R} ^\infty$ to mean all sequences that vanish at infinity. I think the space of all real sequences should be $\mathbb{R} ^ \omega$ in his notation.

Comment: Sorry I did not make this clear enough to start with!

Comment: Please state in the body of the question what $\Bbb R^\infty$ is: all eventually $0$ real sequences or all real sequences?

Comment: It would seem your functions $f_n$ are also continuous in the box topology, since they only vary on finitely many of the coordinates.

Comment: Yes! I have recently just realized that there should be a continuous surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R} ^ \infty$ under both box and uniform topologies. This is because the space is still the union of all these compact spaces and the component functions constructed are still continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pasting lemma works in the particular case you mentioned.
This is basically because if $\{A_i\}$ is a [locally finite collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection), then $\cup \overline{A_i}$ = $\overline {\cup {A_i}}$.

Therefore, for each closed $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\infty$, $f^{-1}(F) = \cup _n f_n^{-1}(F)$ is closed, since the collection $\{f_n ^{-1} (F) \}_n$ is locally finite.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I ignored the local finiteness property!